# How to get Byte Array from PictureBox?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress PictureEdit, I'm trying to get the bytes of the image loaded from the following code

```
byte[] picBytes = picStudent.EditValue as byte[];
```

but it always returns null. How to do it?

Comment: are you serializing and deserializing the picStudent for sending as a byte[]?

Comment: what do you mean by that? I just dragged the PictureEditControl and a button. On the button I wrote that code and trying to get the bytes of image in that picturebox.

Comment: I'm not sure about DevExpress. But in VS, when you have a picture it doesn't get stored as a byte[] by default. you need to serialize it into a byte[] and then deserialize it afterwards to retrieve it.

Comment: didn't found anything you said.

Comment: look at this link. maybe this will help a bit. I don't have my serializer code with me at the moment so i'm sorry i can't be more help. http://www.dzone.com/snippets/convert-object-byte-array-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PictureEdit.EditValue property does not contains byte array at all. This property contains the `System.Drawing.Image` instance ([proof](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsPictureEdit_Imagetopic)). Thus, to get image bytes from PictureEdit use the following approach:

```
Image img = pictureEdit1.EditValue as Image; // or use the PictureEdit.Image property
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```